# Loading multiple stylesheets in Sinatra

Tags: css, sinatra

Is there a limit on how many stylesheets will load with a Sinatra app?
Only one of the stylesheets that I linked will load. I've tried renaming and relocating the one that won't load, but nothing seems to make a difference.

Comment: This isn't really possible I think. But I found this. http://amaras-tech.co.uk/article/143/User_selectable_stylesheets_(Using_Sinatra) maybe that helps.

Comment: what do you mean? You can link to as many css from your view as you like. They can be dynamic (sass) or static (under /public).

Comment: Sinatra has no limits to how many stylesheets you can serve. Sinatra has no concept of stylesheets, per se. How are you serving the files: (1) from a route defined in Sinatra, (2) from Sinatra's `public` directory, or (3) from a CDN or another server? Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: sorry for the delayed re: Arman.. I put the file in the public folder, and then linked both files in my index.erb